# Image on right with div filled with text on left as you collapse page the image drops below the text

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue with some styling. I have an Image on right with div filled with text on left; as you collapse page the image drops below the text and then the text begins wrapping. I would like the image to stay and the text to wrap within its div.

When I have positioned the image to be absolute and I collapse, the image goes over the text.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thank you.

JSFiddle:

jsfiddle.net/nH8bG/1

Comment: Sorry about that. http://jsfiddle.net/nH8bG/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place the image element inside the .introParagraph div, before all the text, or even after should do. Then make it float right, and apply appropriate margin so that it doesn't sit so close to the text. This should make the text wrap underneath it.

And the div with class "right", you can get rid of.